# Smallest squarefree number with $\varphi(n)\mid \sigma(n)$ and smallest prime factor $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

Let $\ p\ge 5\ $ be a prime number.

> How can I efficiently find the smallest squarefree number $\ n\ $ with $\ \varphi(n)\mid \sigma(n)\ $ having $\ p\ $ as the smallest prime factor , where $\sigma(n)\ $ denotes the divisor-sum-function and $\ \varphi(n)\ $ the totient-function ? If it exists , let us denote it as $\ n_p\ $.

Conjectures :

- $n_p$ exists for every prime $\ p\ge 5\ $
- The smallest solution satisfies $\ \sigma(n_p)=2\varphi(n_p)\ $

We have

- $n_5=5\cdot 7$
- $n_7=7\cdot 11\cdot 17\cdot 19$
- $n_{11}=11\cdot 13\cdot 17\cdot 19\cdot 29\cdot 31$
- $n_{13}\le 13\cdot 17\cdot 19\cdot 23\cdot 29\cdot 31\cdot 41\cdot 43$
- $n_{17}\le 17\cdot 19\cdot 23\cdot 29\cdot 31\cdot 37\cdot 41\cdot 43\cdot 47\cdot 71\cdot 97\cdot 229$
- $n_{19}\le 19\cdot 23\cdot 29\cdot 31\cdot 37\cdot 41\cdot 43\cdot 53\cdot 59\cdot 71\cdot 89\cdot 97\cdot 101\cdot 103\cdot 109\cdot 127\cdot 1217$

Comment: Don't $n_2$ and $n_3$ exist and equal $2$ and $3$ respectively?

Comment: @paw88789 Yes, I omitted those cases since the existence and the minimum is trivial.

Comment: ///// 934204276919699018170392101581845929 /////
 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 71 97 107 113 181 199 211 229 241 419 /////

Comment: $n_{23}\le 23\cdot 29\cdot 31\cdot 37\cdot 41\cdot 43\cdot 47\cdot 53\cdot 59\cdot 61\cdot 67\cdot 71\cdot 89\cdot 97\cdot 103\cdot 127\cdot 131\cdot 173\cdot 229\cdot 769\cdot 1117$

Comment: There is a book by Nijenhuis and Wilf  on combinatorial algorithms that  can,  for your purposes, begin with the first $k$   distinct primes   and produce  every subset of $k$ primes out of an alphabet of $n$  primes. Also fast.  Your alphabet could be the primes up to $1250.$   You could, say, fix the smallest prime and tack on every subset of 5 larger primes, or 6.  Up to 25 chosen primes.   Much faster than plowing through all   subsets of a large alphabet   https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/website/CombAlgDownld.html

Comment: alright, the lexicographic method on pages 26,27,28  is the simpler code and is appropriate for finding the smallest successful product of $k$ primes...   if the minimum prime in the $k$-tuple is too large,  for example $p^k >  M$   where $M$ is the smallest product so far, you may stop the process and move on to $k+1$   primes   and $k+2$ primes, in case it is not clear how many primes would be best

Comment: vector for $p=29$ (probably far from optimal) : $$[29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 137, 229, 1427, 1429, 2377, 4663]$$

Comment: And for $p=31$ : $$[31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 197, 199, 211, 223, 229, 311, 409, 1217]$$

Comment: And for $p=37$ : $$[37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 173, 211, 223, 229, 257, 271, 311, 337, 409, 419, 859, 1979]$$

Comment: Peter, how are you finding these?

Comment: Hard to describe (had to experiment with the paramters) : I start with , say , the $25$ first primes starting with the given prime, call this $n$, search $s$ upto , say , $2\cdot 10^5$ such that the denominator gets minimal, multiply $n$ with $s$ and so on until the denominator gets (hopefully) $1$.

Comment: New record for $p=19$ : $$[19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 71, 89, 97, 101, 103, 109, 229]$$

Comment: New record for $p=23$ : $$[23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 61, 71, 73, 79, 89, 97, 101, 103, 109, 149, 229, 311]$$

Comment: New $p=29$: `[29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 103, 131, 149, 163, 229, 311, 337, 521]`

Comment: Let $k(x)=\dfrac{\sigma(x)}{\varphi(x)}$, prime $p\mid n$, $a=numerator(k(n/p))$, $d=denominator(k(n/p))$.

Then if $a\pmod4\equiv 0$, then $k(p)=\dfrac{d}{a/2}$; if $d\pmod2\equiv 0$, then $k(p)=\dfrac{2d}{a}$.

$numerator(k(n)-k(n/p))\mid numerator(k(n))$.

Comment: New $p=29,31,37,41$: `[29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 89, 97, 101, 103, 109, 137, 149, 173, 191, 1117]`

`[31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 89, 97, 101, 103, 109, 113, 127, 137, 139, 149, 173, 191, 229, 257, 311]`

`[37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 137, 139, 149, 163, 173, 191, 211, 229, 257, 311]`

`[41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 173, 181, 191, 197, 199, 229, 257, 311, 317]`